# First deployement questions

Tags: apex, governorlimits

I am ready to deploy my first project, I have a couple of random questions before that

1) I have a form and I am performing insert operation after all the fields are entered and submitted. Here I just don't understand how the governer limits work. Suppose if thousand users insert at the same time will my code break? As salesforce dml operations allow only 1000 records to be inserted at once.

2) what is pagerference, I created a method with pagerference and changed it back to void and I don't find any difference. I went through documentation and still have hard time understanding it. 
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The governor limits are per transaction. If you have 1000 users access the form at once, you are fine. Now if your code tried to insert 1000 records as a result of a single user's action, you'd have trouble.

When you return a page reference, you can direct the user to another page. With a void, you will stay on the same page.

Comment: for my Action Methods, I always define the signature as returning a `pageReference`; if the value returned is null, then VF leaves user on the same page. This is subtly different in specification than an action method with a void signature that, also leaves the user on the same page. An action method is implicitly mimicking the ApexPages.Action class's invoke() method which returns a PageReference. I've always wondered if there is a practical difference.